# Augmented Reality app for SONY Xperia Z2

Tags: android, augmented-reality, sony, sony-xperia, sony-camera-api

We are building one Camera App especially for Sony Xperia Z2 and it’s going to be AR Camera app. below is the key features of the same.

"Need to allow selection of image and detect human once camera is open. User can adjust, rotate, and resize that selected image. Then he can take picture from camera."

So we tried to find some API/SDK for Sony Xperia camera app/AR feature, but did not find a perfect solution yet. So need technical feedback on below few queries. So need expert’s opinion and few sample code of AR if possible.

1. It’s clear to us that Sony is providing an SDK for its high end smart phone series  - http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/camera-add-on-api/

   - It says “The Camera Add-on API enables you to both add a shortcut to your imaging app from the camera apps mode selector, and you can add a shortcut to the smart social camera apps mode selector in your imaging app UI.”
   - So does this adds on provide access to default core AR effect’s API of Z2?
   - We have seen some third party apps are listed under Sony’s default camera mode selection like Evernote, vine etc.
2. Can we have access to core AR effect’s code? Or can we create new AR effects and add under the AR effect mode. Currently all such AR effects are available from Sony Itself.

   - For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.areffect.spider_man_theme
3. If any AR API/Code access is not available from Sony, Can someone please suggest good third party solution or sample demo link for the camera AR feature?

Your prompt response is much more appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The AR effects code and any Sony AR camera app is owned and copyrighted by Sony, they do not share or publish their AR engine to the public.

The Camera Add-on API simply enables you to allow the camera app to appear in the list of camera modes, providing you implement it correctly. I recommend you read up on it and view the included examples [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/camera-add-on-api/)

*Can we create a new AR effect*. You probably could. I don't think Sony would like you to otherwise they would invite devs to add to it. Looking at the existing AR effects apps they all have this permission `com.sonymobile.areffect.permission.THEME`. What else is required to add an AR effect I'm not so sure.

Existing solutions for AR are [Vuforia](https://www.vuforia.com/), which is not free. If you have a lot of time then you could try OpenCV. There are loads of other free open source AR libraries. I think Sony use a customised version of Unity 3D for their AR effects.

Comment: Just one question, I'm unsure if I got you right, Pete. With "The Camera Add-on API simply enables you to allow the camera app to appear in the list of camera modes" You are saying one is able to use the camera for whatever app - maybe using Vuforia - without having to use the Sony-Camer-API, right?

Comment: @Daniel What I mean is the add on API allows you to show your camera app in the list of camera modes and gives you access to the list of camera modes - a common button for quickly accessing other camera modes. You could use Vuforia to make a camera app and add support for the Sony camera add on.